# Creating a socket that can serve concurrent requests simultaneously

Tags: c#, sockets

Assuming the following code:

```
Task.Run(()=>{
     while(true){
         Socket connection = socket.Accept(); // Problem
         Task.Run(()=> { //Receive from and Send to connection } )
     }
})
```

Although it is capable of serving connections in a multi-threaded way, all requests are served one after another and not in a fully concurrent way since the `socket.Accept()` is in the while loop. On the other hand, it cannot be moved into the inner task since it that case, an infinite (very large and unknown) number of `accept()` will be created.

What is the proper solution for this problem?

Example:

```
 Connection A -- Accepted at 3:30:00:00 PM
 Connection B -- Accepted at 3:30:00:00 PM
 Instead of 
 Connection A -- Accepted at 3:30:00:00 PM
 Connection B -- Accepted at 3:30:00:50 PM
```

Comment: You should have multiple sockets to call accept on.

Comment: @VuVirt: Multiple sockets?? how many then ??? No, that's not the solution. A silly person can fake things like that.

Comment: You should create a new socket for every new connection, and keep the original one for listening for new connections

Comment: @mousetail: sorry but you have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: It seems from the docks a new socket is made automatically in the default C# socket library. You can use the AcceptAsync method to line 3 won't hang.

Comment: @mousetail: Your second comment is even worse which shows that you really really have no idea what you are talking about!

Comment: I indeed have not worked with networking in .Net sockets specifically, but have done similar things with other libraries. Your problem indeed seems a bit to complicated for my level of understanding.

Comment: When you say 'very large' what do you mean? Node.js works on a single thread and is more then capable of handling large amount of traffic. But I think you are not working on a really large scale so micro optimization is unnecessary. But for simple socket manipulation core team did benchmarks for the [socket handling](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks/blob/dev/experimental/HttpBenchmark/Program.cs) in c#

Comment: @FilipCordas: You misunderstood, you read the question then you find what the question actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be a couple of things going on here. Unfortunately, we don't get to see how you are using the `socket` object that gets returned by the `accept` method - and there may be some pitfalls there which can cause a delay - but in general, it is not possible to accept connections in strict parallel.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept(v=vs.110).aspx),

> Accept synchronously extracts the first pending connection request
>   from the connection request queue of the listening socket, and then
>   creates and returns a new Socket.

So, .NET keeps (accesses) a queue of pending requests from the underlying OS (and important to note that this queue length is limited by the OS). Based on how TCP/IP works, only one client can be served at a time on a single socket. So, what happens is that one client connects, you call `accept` and a new TCP socket on a different (usually high numerical value) port is created for that client, which is returned by the accept method. This necessarily must happen in a serial fashion. *The only way to **initially** connect multiple clients in parallel is to have multiple listening ports.*